# XML view in iframe not shown as 'xml' but as text

Tags: jsf, jasper-reports

I need to generate a xml report in XML format but not in text view. 
[Current display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ok5tu.png)

My modal should display something like this. 
[As expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hv72w.png)

I coded preRenderView bean.show() in reportdisplay.xhtml

xHtml:

```
<p:dialog header="Report Preview" modal="true" widgetVar="reportDialog" 
 maximizable="true" width = "800" height="500" resizable="false">
     <iframe src="about:blank" name="iframe_a"></iframe>            
    <h:outputLink id ="rptDisp" value="reportdisplay.xhtml" title="Report Preview" target="iframe_a"/>
</p:dialog>
```

Bean:

```
public void show() {
    FacesContext faces = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) faces.getExternalContext().getResponse();

    response.setHeader("cache-control", "max-age=1");
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", reportModel.getContentDisposition());
    response.setContentType(reportModel.getContentType());
    response.setContentLength(reportModel.getReport().length);
    ServletOutputStream ouputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    ouputStream.write(reportModel.getReport(), 0, reportModel.getReport().length);

    ouputStream.flush();
    ouputStream.close();

    faces.responseComplete();
}
```

I able to load PDF view in the iframe within the modal but not in XML format.

Comment: Is it possible to display XML format view in the IFrame ?

Comment: So it works if you don't use a PrimeFaces `p:dialog` but just an `iframe`?

Comment: Nope. It shows only texts

Comment: Then it is not PrimeFaces related. did you check the contentType? and the content-disposition. And how is this jasper-reports related? Does it work using a xml text file as input? Narrow down the problem

Comment: What does reportModel.getReport() return? If this is not the raw xml.. then you will not see the raw xml.